# Is there a way to put a function in a procedure and then have the output of the procedure input into a table?

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

It is as the title asks If you need to see the code let me know.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Intrest 
    (@loan MONEY, @interest MONEY)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue INT
    SET @returnValue = (@loan) * (@interest)

    INSERT INTO Loan (Loan_amount, Interest_rate)
    VALUES (@loan, @interest)

    RETURN @returnValue 
END
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE Getoutput 
    (@loanamount MONEY, @interestrate MONEY) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @loansID INT

    SELECT @loansID = Loan_id 
    FROM Loan
    WHERE  Loan_amount = @loanamount

    SELECT dbo.Intrest (@loanamount, @interestrate) 

    INSERT INTO Loan (Outputs, Loan_amount, Interest_rate)
    VALUES (@loansID, @loanamount, @interestrate)

    RETURN @@identity 
END
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of  `@@IDENTITY` to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: So in the brackets I am creating a new variable and having it insert into the output table?

Comment: you call the function in your procedure, but do not store the result of the function. If you dont need the result, then why make it a function ?

Comment: That is what I am asking how to store the result so I can have it populate in the output table

Comment: select @MyVariable = dbo.Intrest (@loanamount, @interestrate)

Comment: When i do that it wants me to declare a scalar which defeats the whole purpose of using the function in the first place. I have have to have another variable to input then that is just the result of the function. I am trying to get it to dbo.Intrest 3,000, 0.03 and then it should input into the table column output the reslut

Comment: Please edit your question and explain this there. People will not read all the comments, only the question.

Comment: Try to explain in other words what you are looking for. As it stands I have no clue anymore what your exact question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function cannot perform any DML operation on table. I have remove the `INSERT` statement

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Intrest 
    (@loan MONEY, @interest MONEY)
RETURNS INT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @returnValue INT
    SET @returnValue = (@loan) * (@interest)

    RETURN @returnValue 
END
GO
```

The variables are not necessary. Your `Stored Procedure` can be simplify to

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Getoutput 
    (@loanamount MONEY, @interestrate MONEY) 
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Loan (Outputs, Loan_amount, Interest_rate)
    SELECT Loan_id, Loan_amount,  dbo.Intrest (Loan_amount, @interestrate) 
    FROM   Loan
    WHERE  Loan_amount = @loanamount

    RETURN @@identity 

END
```

Comment: Thank you for that I had to get some sleep was up till 2 am. So I am guessing that there is not way to work SQL like Excel. So in this case this is all in one table. For example 1+1=2 those are essentially my columns the 1's are loan amount and interest rate and the 2 is the output.  Now all my rows in excel match the columns but in SQL I am unsure how to take the output of the function in my procedure and have it inserted into the output column. So there is a flow of information.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to say, please post as a new question